# Collect results from parallel Celery task executions

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am trying to achieve a rather simple Celery workflow, where I receive the result of multiple parallel invocations of the same task as a tuple (or list).

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def master():
    return group(add.s(1, 2), add.s(3, 4))()
```

From this, I would like to retrieve `(3, 7)` *in a generic way*, that is, in a way that does not depend on the workflow itself. I am looking for some sort of "reduce async result graph to primitives" operation. I have experimented with the following (I have replaced result IDs with `#num` for brevity)

```
r = master.delay()
r.get()      # <GroupResult: #1 [#2, #3]>
r.collect()  # [(<AsyncResult: #0>, <GroupResult #1 [#2, #3]>),
             #  (<GroupResult: #1 [#2, #3]>, [3, 7])
             #  (<AsyncResult: #2>, 3),
             #  (<GroupResult: #3>, 7)]
```

`r.get()` returns a wrapper around two `AsyncResult` IDs, so I would have to process each one recursively. `r.collect()` is close, but it recurses too deeply.

I could do something like

```
r.children[0].get()
```

but this is not generic, since it explicitly depends on the structure of the result graph. Also, I could iterate through `r.collect()` until I find a tuple whose value is not an instance of `ResultBase`, like

```
next(value for _, value in r.collect() if not isinstance(value, ResultBase))
```

but I am not sure if this is actually correct in all cases, and I was hoping that there is a more elegant way to do this.

If there is a way of restructuring the `master` task to make retrieving the results easier, I am open to it, just as long as the subtasks are launched in parallel. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

---

**EDIT** A related issue is that if I want to retrieve the task results in a non-blocking way (for example, by manually polling `r.status` before calling `r.get()` or `r.collect()`, I cannot simply do this

```
r = master.delay()

# some time later...
if r.status in READY_STATES:
    r.get()
```

because `r` is an `AsyncResult` which resolves to a `GroupResult`, i.e. it completes before the `GroupResult` or its children. Is there a way to invoke the group in a way that "skips" the top-level `AsyncResult`? This would solve both issues, since `r.status` and `r.get()` would reflect the status and value of the child task, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the correct solution turned out to be the simplest one: call `master` as a function to execute it in the current process.

```
r = master()
r.get()      # [3, 7]
r.collect()  # [(<GroupResult: #1 [#2, #3]>, [3, 7]),
             #  (<AsyncResult: #2>, 3),
             #  (<AsyncResult: #3>, 7)]
```

Instead of deferring the `group` startup code to a worker process, it is started in the current process. Since the `group` is entirely asynchronous, the behavior does not change, and the performance improves.

Comment: I'm facing a similar challenge that you had currently and having much trouble. can you perhaps share a larger portion of the code? Where do you store `r.collect()`, does it block? Do you have a `for` loop? a `while` loop?

Comment: Is this done to collect the results after the group has finished, or while the group of jobs is happening?